# Alpha/Beta radiation and photoionisation of air

Tags: plasma-physics, ionization-energy, laser-interaction

Which type of radiation is more likely to lower breakdown threshold when using focal lense focused pulse laser,for example 1064nm Nd:YAG.

I reed three studies that said free electrons are most important to initiate the avalanche breakdown,since beta radiation are free electrons,I would think that beta radiation would have biggest impact on the air breakdown threshold.I also heard conflicting opinion that alpha radiation will have biggest effect becose it penetrates less far,it will interact more with the small area of focal point where photoionisation happens.

I would like to represent alpha radiation by Americium 241,alpha emiter used in smoke alarms,and beta radiation with Caesium 137,a beta emiter used for example in Raytheon CK1097-7 spark gap tube to aid ionisation.Which of these two radioactive isotopes will have greater effect on laser induced breakdown when placed in close proximity to the focal point area ( few milimeters ) in quantity around 1 to 100 miligrams?

Right now I am of opinion that for conducting current as sort of bridge between anode and cathode that are connected to power source,a alpha radiation with its stronger charge and more concentrated area of effect would be stronger than beta,but thats different that photoionisation in air,there is no anode,cathode or power source,becose like I written at the begining,the studies said that electrons specificaly have greatest impact,a alpha radiation is helium 4 nucleus without electrons,while its strongly charged,it doesnt "bring" new electrons into the focal point area like beta emiter would.

To clarify,I ask what type of radiation will make the air more opaque to the laser beam,the problem in photoionisation threshold is to first get the gas to start absorbing the beam by turning opaque.I understand alpha radiation have more ionisation energy,but does that translate to making the air more opaque than beta?

Just want to mention that dust particles, lower photoionisation threshold by multiple orders of magnitude! Thats massive difference,and it doesnt matter if the particles are conductive or electrical insulator,thats becose photoionisation is much different than your spark gap ionisation with electrodes.Its about absorbtion of photons,not electrical conductivity.

Comment: Frankly you are not going to get enough ionization to make he air opaque from any source you can get. You should be thinking about a multiple step process in which a small amount of ionization allows some other process (perhaps a high-voltage spark) to occur and magnify the level of ionization by orders of magnitude. (Anecdote: One of the techs at a lab I worked with took some radiation monitors that needed calibration at high rates to a site where they had megacurie sources manipulated by remote waldos; no lack of visibility near the sources except from the leaded glass view port.)

Comment: But 1064nm is invisible infrared wavelenght,things that are transparent to visible light can be opaque to infrared and vice versa.Also I dont really expect to actualy see the "opaque" air,by word opaque I mean absorbing the laser instead of being transparent to it.The studies I reed showed that about 95% was absorbed and 5% transmited through,while its not 100%,I call that opaque.

Comment: If you measure the strength of your source in milligrams then I'm not sure you should consider doing this experiment. Are you familiar with the Becquerel unit, and how activity is measured/ expressed?

Comment: yes I do,I have been thinking for some time that there must be some formula where you input type of radiation,Becquerel rate and then cm3 focal point area size and it would tell you how it will affect the breakdown threshold.For example 1000 Becquerel of 1.176 MeV beta will decrease the threshold of 0.1 cm3 focal point by 5%

Answer (score 2):

The ionization density of alphas is much higher as they range out than that of electrons. So, if your need it to make a region of gas significantly ionized then alphas are a good bet.

On the other hand, alphas range out over very short distances even in air while betas will carry for modest distance, so if your need to to have a non-trivial length of track with *some* ionization then betas are a better choice.

Comment: but why would then the Raytheon spark gap tube use beta radiation in form of Caesium 137  and not Americium 241? Caesium have much shorter half life,its harder to shield,and its ionization performance is alot less like you say,why would then they use it to help generate plasma?        What I really want is plasma,plasma is always ions but ionisation isnt always plasma.What I am instersted in is what type of radiation will make the gas more opaque to the laser beam.

Comment: As I say in the post, the length of the ionization track may be more important than the ionization density. There is a trade-off here, and you have to balance desires. Without knowing a lot more about the engineering of a particular device I couldn't even begin to reconstruct how the person who designed it might have been thinking. Instead I have just told you about some relevant properties of the radiation alternatives you suggested.

Comment: But the point  I still dont understand is if the higher ionisation density of alpha matters when we talk mid air photoionisation,I am sure it matter if we want to conduct electricity between two points like anode and cathode then it will conduct more than beta,but this is different and I am not sure if its still the more effective of the two radiation types mentioned,

Comment: I have offered no comment on which you want. I don't know which you want. I'm just feeding you some raw basics that you need to even get started.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have both of these sources, or if your design is very sensitive, then you should just do the experiment.  One possibility is that each source has a slightly different geometry where it is most effective at producing ionization.  My intuition is that an alpha source would be better, but I wouldn't be surprised either way.

The conduction electrons in the air don't come from the radiation source directly, but from its interactions with the air.  Ionizing one air molecule takes some finite amount energy that you can look up, probably from the NIST data websites, one the scale of about 10 eV.  So you can roughly predict the number of electron-ion pairs produced in air per decay by looking up the energy that the charged particles carry away.

Americium-241 emits 5.4 MeV alpha particles.  Cesium-137 emits beta particles with a [mean energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/beta.html#c5) of a few hundred kilo-eV. So if you treat the scattering probabilities the same way (not correct, but not terrible) then you'd expect perhaps twenty times as many electron-ion pairs in the air from each alpha particle than from each beta particle.

However there are lots of sneaky things that can happen in systems like this --- which is why if you really care, you should obtain both sorts of source and make a comparison measurement.

Comment: The full *Particle Data Book* has a table of common ionization potentials in the chapter on "The Passage of Radiation Through Matter". That's probably easier than finding the data in the maze of twistly little web pages all alike that is NIST.

Comment: I know the conductivy would be higher with alpha,but I am not sure if it matters in photoionisation,which is different to electrode ionisation.For example dust and other small particles of electrical isolator material would significantly lower the  plasma threshold for pulse laser,but would do exact oposite for spark gap!!!  Its becose for photoionisation if they conductive or not doesnt matter,what matters is that they are opaque so they absorb the laser beam and hardest step in photoionisation is get throught that transition from transparent air to absorbing air.